# Aligning a subtitle underneath a title and to the last letter of the title

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've made a few sites out of bootstrap templates, but I'm starting from scratch with just the bootstrap css and jsquery but I keep running into problems with premade styles for `<a>`, `<p>` etc..

I can overwrite these in my own stylesheet so that's what I did but I need help alligning a subtitle under a title and so that it text-alligns: right; but doesn't go to the div width but only so far as the title text goes.

http://deliciousproductions.com.au/thepeople.com.au

The title links to the original site so you can see the look I want to achieve with the subtitle.

```
 <section id="top">
    <div class="container topbg">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4-offset-lg-4 text-center">
                <div>
                <span class="thepeople" onclick="location='http://thepeople.com.au'">the people</span>
                <p><span class="agency" onclick="location='http://thepeople.com.au'">agency</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I'm not sure how to post the css without cluttering this post. If you understand my question please answer :)

I used col-lg-4 and then offset it by 4 (or a third) to get it centered. I was just using text-center, still am but I thought I could align the text to the edge of a div but I realise it's gonna be extremely finicky to get the div the exact width of the text..?

Comment: An image of what you are trying to do would be more help...it's not clear at the moment.

Comment: If you feel you must include all your code, you could put it in a snippet, and check the "hidden snippet" box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it this you want to achieve?

```css
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;  
}

.thepeople {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: red;
}
.agency {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <span class="thepeople" onclick="location='http://thepeople.com.au'">the people</span>
  <p><span class="agency" onclick="location='http://thepeople.com.au'">agency</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: yes this is it! I'll adjust the padding so it's closer to the people text but yes it is thanks. And sorry for not replying sooner I had it set up so I get an email when there's replies but I only got an email with an "update" saying there were 4 new posts. 

cheers :) Nik

Answer (score 1):

Make the containing div `inline-block` then it will collapse to it's own width.

Then use block level elements like headings (*which are more semantic anyway*) rather than spans which can have their text aligned independently.

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-block;
}
.agency {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section id="top">
  <div class="container topbg">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4-offset-lg-4 text-center">
        <div class="parent">
          <h2 class="thepeople" onclick="location='http://thepeople.com.au'">the people</h2>
          <h3 class="agency" onclick="location='http://thepeople.com.au'">agency</h3> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: hey you got it too and added the bootstrap cdn, I don't know why you were downvoted..? Cheers! :)